# C: Segmentation Fault on pthread_create

Tags: c, pthreads, segmentation-fault

I am getting a Segmentation Fault error when running my program in GCC. This is quite a long program so I am only posting the parts which I believe are relevant; please let me know if more is required.

```
void *RelaxThread(void *para) {
    printf("Entering RelaxThread...\n");
    struct Parameter *parameters;
    parameters = (struct Parameter *) para;
    /*Some code here*/
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int relax(double **matrix, int size, int threads, double precision) {
    keepRunning = 0;
    int rowAllocation = (size-2) / threads;     
    struct Parameter para[threads];
    pthread_t threadcount[threads];
    int current;
    int startRow = 1;
    long t;    
    for(t=0; t<threads; t++){       
        para[t].matrix = matrix;
        para[t].size = size;
        para[t].threads = threads;
        para[t].precision = precision;
        para[t].allocation = rowAllocation;
        para[t].threadId = t;
        para[t].startRow = startRow;
        startRow += rowAllocation;
        printf("DebugMsg1\n");
        current = pthread_create(&threadcount[t], NULL, RelaxThread, (void *) &para[t]);
        printf("DebugMsg2\n");
    }
    void *status;
    int rc;
    for(t=0; t<threads; t++) {
        rc = pthread_join(threadcount[t], &status);
        if (rc) {
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    if (keepRunning) {
        printf("Iterating...\n");
        relax(matrix, size, threads, precision); 
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int const size = 8;
    int const threads = 2;
    double const precision = 1e-6;
    double **matrix = (double **) malloc(size * sizeof(double));
    populateMatrix(matrix, size);
    relax(matrix, size, threads, precision);
    free(matrix);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The code runs fine when size is set to 8 or below. However anything larger than this (it only supports even numbers for now) gives a segmentation fault on the second iteration of relax(). The debug messages therefore run as:

```
Debug1
Debug2
Debug1
Debug2
Entering RelaxThread...
Entering RelaxThread...
Iterating...
Debug1
Debug2
Debug1
Segmentation Fault
```

The fact that this runs where size is 8 or less but crashes above this number has completely confused me, and I have spent a long time trying to work out why this is happening. I completely acknowledge that my code is neither the neatest nor most efficient, but would greatly appreciate some advice as to why this is failing.

Edit 1: attaching GDB backlog as requested.

```
Debug1
[New Thread 0x40040940 (LWP 23270)]
Debug2
Debug1
Entering RelaxThread...
Entering RelaxThread 0
[New Thread 0x40081940 (LWP 23271)]
Debug2
Entering RelaxThread...
Entering RelaxThread 1
[Thread 0x40040940 (LWP 23270) exited]
Main: completed join with thread 0 having a status of 0
Main: completed join with thread 1 having a status of 0
Iterating...
Debug1
[Thread 0x40081940 (LWP 23271) exited]
[New Thread 0x40081940 (LWP 23272)]
Debug2
Debug1
```

Edit2: updated the backtrace log following changes.

Edit3: the below is the full RelaxThread

```
    void *RelaxThread(void *para) {
        struct Parameter *parameters;
        parameters = (struct Parameter *) para;
        double **matrix = parameters->matrix;
        int size = parameters->size;
        double precision = parameters->precision;
        int threads = parameters->threads;
        int threadId = parameters->threadId;
        int startRow = parameters->startRow;
        int allocation = parameters->allocation;
        int finishRow = (startRow + allocation);
        int i;
        int j;
        double oldValue;
        double newValue;
        double difference;
        for(i=startRow;i<finishRow;i++) {
            for (j=1;j<size-1;j++) {
                pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexmatrix); //Tested with and without the mutex, which is globally defined and initialised elsewhere
                oldValue = matrix[i][j];
                newValue = ((matrix[i+1][j] + matrix[i-1][j] + matrix[i][j+1] + matrix[i][j-1]) / 4);
                matrix[i][j] = newValue;
                pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexmatrix);
                difference = oldValue - newValue;
                if(difference < 0) {
                    difference = -difference; 
                }
                //printf("Precision on thread%d: %f , aiming for %f\n",threadId, difference,precision);
                if (difference > precision) {
                    keepRunning = 1;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh, how I love threads, segfaulting deep in the library methods with nary a line of my code in the backtrace...  Anyway, this is fairly small so not too bad, but if you could pare it down to a [working example in as few lines as possible](http://sscce.org/), that would be even better.

Comment: Oh, and speaking of the backtrace, could you post it? `gdb myprogram`, `r` to run it (add arguments if needed), wait for it to segfault, and type `bt`.  Then add it to your post.

Comment: First, you should not initialize arrays with dynamic size this way: `struct Parameter para[threads];`, as this is not a ANSI-C feature, some compilers will allow that, some won't.

Comment: @Kevin Attached the backtrace, thanks.

Comment: @felipemaia: That is a standard ANSI-C feature as of C99.  It is well-supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper initialization, assuming a squared matrix would be:

```
double **matrix = malloc(size * sizeof(double *));
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(double));
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = 0; // removing the junk contents
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I also realized you never actually initialize `void *status`. Since you're not using it, change it to `rc = pthread_join(threadcount[t], NULL);`, that's surely another problem.

EDIT3:
Another problem I found is `int startRow = 1;`, I do not see how you're accessing the matrix, but it's index should start as 0.

EDIT4:
Also, when you free a two dimensional array you need to do it this way:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    free(matrix[i]);    //Free each row pointer
}
free(matrix);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I've made the correction. Unfortunately the crash does appear to still be happening in the same place.

Comment: What do you do inside /*Some code here*/? Is there actual code there or would you add it later?

Comment: There's currently code there, which iterates through the matrix from startRow for rowAllocation number of rows and replaces each cell with the average of its four neighbours. I.e. a relaxation implementation. It then checks to see if the difference between the old value and the new value is greater than the specified precision, and if so flags keepRunning to 1 to signal that relax() should be run again. I didn't include that code since I assumed the problem was with pthread_create

Comment: Corrected pthread_join as suggested, however the crash continues

Comment: Declare these variables as globals to see if it works `struct Parameter para[32];` and `pthread_t threadcount[32];`

Comment: I'll try that, however I beleive the compiler I'm using does allow that.

Comment: I can only believe now that the issue is inside `/*Some code here*/`, can you remove it and see if it runs?

Comment: It runs until the 14678th iteration and then crashes; I'm not quite sure why. I'll update the original post with the code from that function. Thanks again for your help with everything, it really is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ah, sorry forgot to say on Edit3: I am iterating through every cell in the matrix except for the boundary values, hence why I am beginning at 1.

Comment: After commenting out line-by-line it appears the problem lies with matrix[i][j] = newValue;

Comment: On the 14678th iteration? Segmentation fault again, but only after relax() is called, so at a different point in the program.

Comment: Put this before `oldValue = matrix[i][j];` `if(i < 1 || j < 1 || i >= size-1 || j >= size-1) printf("shit hit the fan, %d %d", i, j);`

Comment: Added, doesn't come up before the crash, though the crash is when pthread_t is called for the last time on the second iteration. I can only assume something is wrong with the way in which I am assigning newValue to matrix[i][j] which seems to cause that crash.

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue, thank you very much for all your help and patience. I am in your debt.

Comment: Unfortunately it was my stupidity; it turns out there was a line hidden in my code in another part of the program which was overwriting the malloc you outlined in your initial answer. The whole thing works very well now except for on more than 4 threads, though I beleive this is down to my implementation and I'm sure I can fix it. I apologise for my stupidity wasting your time; the initial answer was completely correct and ultimately fixed the program.

Comment: @Myn I'm glad I could help. Best of luck to you.